# Fetching large documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb that stores activities of customers like product_view, added_to_cart etc with productId. I need this data to display products to my customer when he visits next. 
Right now I am thinking to store all data of a customer in a single document,such as  with customer_id as key and corresponding activities in array like product_view activities in product_view array etc.
This will be fast to fetch for me as all data of a customer will be in one key only, but my consideration is that data size will go on increasing always this way. Moreover I may need to check say last 50-100 activities of a customer only. For that too I need to fetch the entire document.
What will be the best way to store this data. Request for data will be very very frequent. How can I manage response time ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question answers itself. Have customer activity as separate collection with reference to customerId. Any time customer visits, you know customerId, hence can apply filter/aggregate operations to get whatever you want. 
This way you can do paginated fetch of customer activities.